# Vue Object values

Tags: vue.js

I would like to get an array of the values of a Vue Object.

Object.values(obj) does not work as Vue translates object values to getters/setters: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html

Comment: What object? The whole Vue instance?

Comment: An object passed in as a Vue instnace's data

Answer (score 2):

It does work (see below). Since you are looking for **the whole `data` object**, you can get it by `Object.values(this.$data)`:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    message: 'Open the console for a better view',
    person: {
     name: {first_name: 'Alice', surname: 'Smith'},
      age: 15
    }
  },
  methods: {
    print() {
      console.log(Object.values(this.person));
      console.log(Object.values(this.person.name));

      console.log(Object.values(this.$data));
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue"></script>

<div id="app">
  <p>{{ message }}</p>
  <button @click="print">print</button>
</div>
```